# Are there procedures in probability problems that can't be repeated an infinite number of times?

Tags: probability

On the Wikipedia page of definitions, "experiment" is defined as a procedure that is well defined and can be repeated an infinite number of times. Are there procedures that can't be repeated an infinite number of times? It seems like if a procedure can be done once, it can be done any number of times.

Comment: The 'experiments' used here is theoretical. You can do them an infinite number of times (by definition). It's not referring to an actual physical experiment,, although it may be (closely) related to a theoretical counterpart. For example, I can consider an experiment of rolling a pair of dice and taking the sum of them. This procedure may be performed infinitely times (it's a theoretical experiment, I am not actually rolling any dice)

Comment: We can't draw marbles from a bin without replacement forever if the bin starts with a finite number of marbles.

Comment: What is the Probability that there are aliens in this Universe ? What is the Probability that Plato wanted meat when writing ? What is the Probability that $\e^\pi$ is rational ? What is the Probability that Candidate X will win the Elections in 2024 ? What is the Probability that $1=0$ ? [ We can not "repeat" those "Experiments" !! ]

Comment: That "Experiment" is still Possible : Start with the Same number of marbles , Draw the marbles without replacement , then go back to "Starting State" to repeat the "Overall Experiment" forever , @JohnDouma

Comment: I'm not interested in whether or not an actual person can do the actual experiment. I'm thinking in the conceptual/theoretical realm. I think of an experiment as a well-defined process. So, for the marble taken out of a bin, if the experiment described taking 20 marbles out of a bin of 10 marbles without replacement, I'd say that the experiment is not well-defined or is impossible. It can't be done even once, the question repeatability doesn't apply.

Comment: Regarding Plato wanting meat, that's a poorly defined experiment. That's like asking, "What's the probability of heads?" The conditions must be specified: "If a fair coin is flipped once, what's the probability of heads?" If the conditions are added to the Plato question properly, you'll get an experiment. I believe that, in theory (even if not in real life), that experiment will be able to be repeated. Regarding the candidate, if the conditions are specified and the probability calculated, then the repeated experiment is to imagine the candidate running for office any number of times...

Comment: ...with the same starting conditions. This is easy to do conceptually. Thus, repeated experiments. This logic applies to every example given above. So, I still haven't seen a well defined experiment that can't be repeated.

Comment: @Alborz   I hear you saying that every experiment is theoretically repeatable. Then  do you agree that the Wiki definition doesn't need to specify repeatability? It could just say, "An experiment is a well-defined procedure."?

Comment: @delusionist repeatability is worth emphasizing for legitimate reasons. One very common way to view probability (of an event occuring) is as capturing information about it's *long-run frequency* - that is, the ratio of how often the event occurs to the total number of 'repetitions' of the experiment. If you don't specify repeatability in the definition, then this model of probability is weakened or even meaningless. How to interpret $P(E)=0.5$ without allowing that the experiment (that E is an event in) to be repeatable? There are ways, but the way mentioned is very intuitive.

Comment: There may be other good reasons too, that I'm not aware of and maybe someone can supplement my answer

Answer (score 1):

Think of drawing balls from an urn **without replacement**.  When all the balls are drawn, the experiment cannot be repeated again!

Comment: The particular experiment must end when all the balls are drawn from the urn. "Without replacement" is what happens during an experiment, not once the experiment is finished. Once the experiment is finished, the balls can be replaced and the experiment repeated. Each repetition of an experiment starts from the beginning of the description of the experiment, not from the end of the last experiment. Every experiment is like this.